# Python function for api call

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a common function for a couple of api calls using python as below -

```
import json
import requests

def api_call(url,payload,headers,request_type,auth):
    response = requests.request(request_type, url, payload, auth, headers)
    return response
```

While this works when I use directly outside a function, it throws an exception as below when I call the function and pass args as below.

```
url = "https://api.xxxxxx"

payload = json.dumps({
  "Ids": ["12345","69845"],
  "startDate": "2022-01-01",
  "endDate": "2022-05-10"
})

headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'x-api-key': 'yyyyyyyy'}

request_type = 'post'
auth = None

resp = api_call(url=url, payload=payload, headers=headers, request_type=request_type, auth=auth)
```

The error I see is as below -

```
TypeError: request() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

How can I resolve this?
Can someone please guide me.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to give named arguments like `data=payload, headers=headers)` in your `requests.request()` call.

Comment: Are you sure it worked outside of the function? As the error states, only the first two parameters are positional. The others keywords.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to reverse your function like this,

```
def api_call(url,payload,headers,request_type,auth):
    response = requests.request(request_type, url, payload=payload, headers=headers)
    return response
```

Since `auth = None` you don't need to pass that.

```
request(method, url, **kwargs):
```

- `method` and `url` are positional parameters and rest is keyword arguments